# How do I populate a factory without knowing the classes in advance?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to create a generalize factory that builds any classes defined in a script.  However I'm having trouble finding all the classes.

I have `factory.py`:

```
import sys
import inspect

def imports():
    for name, val in globals().items():
        if isinstance(val, types.ModuleType):
            yield val.__name__

def classes():
    for mod in [sys.modules[__name__]] + [imports()]:
        for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(mod):
            if inspect.isclass(obj):
                yield obj
class Factory:
    factory_dict = {}
    def __init__(self):
        for xx in classes():
            factory_dict[xx.__name__] = xx
            print(xx.__name__)
```

I've defined some classes in `myclasses.py`

```
class A:...

class B:...
```

And I have my `scratch.py`:

```
import factory
import myclasses
class foo:...

ff = factory.Factory()
```

The result is this:

```
/Users/raysalemi/.conda/envs/untitled/bin/python scratch.py"
Factory
generator
```

I don't see the classes defined in `myclasses.py` or the class defined in `scratch.py`. Clearly the factory is working only on what it sees in its own module.

Is there a way to create a factory that could access all the currently defined classes?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the solution here was not to inspect the script and find the classes, but instead to have the classes add themselves to the `factory_dict` when they are defined.

The above changes like this:

`factory.py` now defines a metaclass that populates the dict:

```
class Factory:
    factory_dict = {}

class factory_class(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, clsdict):
        Factory.factory_dict[cls.__name__] = cls
        super().__init__(name, bases, clsdict)

class factory_base(metaclass=factory_class):
    pass
```

Classes that want to be available in the factory extend `factory_base`:

```
from factory import factory_base

class A(factory_base):...

class B(factory_base):...
```

The result is simpler code in `scratch.py`:

```
import factory
import myclasses
class foo:...

ff = factory.Factory()
print(factory.Factory.factory_dict)
```

With this output:

```
/python scratch.py"
{'factory_base': <class 'factory.factory_base'>, 'A': <class 'myclasses.A'>, 'B': <class 'myclasses.B'>}
```